# EPOCH time in M Language

Tags: powerbi, m

How can I convert current datetime to epoch/unix time in seconds?

The functions listed below do not offer this as far as I can see..

[DateTime functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/datetime-functions)

in C# it would be done this way

```
var epoch = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something quite similar in M:

```
epoch = Duration.TotalSeconds(DateTimeZone.UtcNow() - #datetimezone(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```